# pyqt5 GUI looks different in raspberry pi than in QtCreator

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI in QtCreator under windows, then converting the .ui file to .py with pyuic5 then moving the generated .py file to raspberry. but the GUI looks very different in raspbian... for example the groupboxes on the raspberry (raspbian) has no border, and the title of the groupbox has a huge font... also in general fonts sizes seem completely random... is this because I create the gui in windows and the use it in the raspberry?

Comment: try with: `QApplication.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: ok that solved the groupbox style, thanks. anyway I had finally to install qtcreator on the raspberry and create the gui there, this way everything show exactly the same it seems...